# Contain Text within HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using html canvas and don't have a huge amount of experience with it. I am take the the text from a textarea and outputting it on the html canvas. Thats works fine but I am struggling to contain the text with canvas, instead it just stay on one line and goes out of the canvas area.

I tried using a maxWidth but that doesn't seem to work and I wondering if anyone has any ideas or how to achieve this?

I have attached screenshots of the input and the result I am currently getting. I tried putting it together in a jsfiddle but it doesn't work right there for some reason. You can view it here if it helps - https://jsfiddle.net/whggn6vb/3/. Below is the main function I am using to draw the text on the canvas.

```
    function updateCanvas() {
    var maxWith = canvas.width;
       context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
       context.textAlign = "center";

       context.font = "bold 36px Open Sans";
       context.fillText($('#quottext').val(), canvas.width * 0.5, 100);

       context.font = "14px Open Sans";
       context.fillText($('#quotauthor').val(), canvas.width * 0.5, 200);   
}
```

[image: Text Area that input to canvas]

[image: Output on Canvas]

Answer (score 0):

hi if i get you right you should be able to do what you need with measureText()

context.measureText(txt).width

how ever if you pick a big font it'll display big

Comment: I essentially want the text size to remain the same but go onto a new line when it gets wider than the width of the canvas. I've tried context.measureText(txt).width but doesn't seem to work for me. I could be doing something wrong though.